# how does count in c++ stl set work?

Tags: c++, count, set

So, I'm trying to check whether a particular object is already present in the set. For this, I use the count() method. Now, it doesn't seem to return the right answer. Let me explain the problem a bit more clearly --

I have declared a class this way

```
class Node{
        public:
                Node(int _state=0, int _cost=0)
                {
                        state = _state;
                        cost = _cost;
                }

                bool operator<(const Node& rhs)
                {
                        return cost < rhs.cost;
                }

                bool operator==(const Node& rhs)
                {
                        cout << "== operator method used" << endl;
                        if (rhs.state == state)
                                return true;
                        return false;
                }

                int state;
                int cost;
};
```

in my code, I declare a set like this --

```
set<Node*> myset;
```

after a few insertions, myset is like this {{1, 5}, {2, 6}, {3, 9}}

now I check whether {1, 7} is part of the set. How would it do it? I have written a operator== method in Node class, which is never called. Then on what basis does count() check if the object is already in the set?... I would want the count to work in a fashion that if {1, 5} is already there in myset, it should view {1, 7} as a duplicate entry.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> how does count in c++ stl set work?

It uses `operator<` by default.

In fact, in general, C++ Standard Library containers use `!(a < b) && !(b < a)` to determine the property of *equivalence*.

You can override the comparator used to perform this check by providing your own `Compare` template argument to the container type, though there is rarely a reason to — you should usually simply define `operator<` for your type instead, as you have done. (Make sure that it creates a Strict Weak Ordering, though.)

> in my code, I declare a set like this --
>
> ```
> set<Node*> myset;
> ```
>
> after a few insertions, myset is like this {{1, 5}, {2, 6}, {3, 9}}

No, your set is never like this. Your set contains *pointers*, not `Node`s. Make it a `set<Node>` instead.

Comment: i want my ordering to be w.r.t to cost variable, but my duplicate element resolution to be w.r.t to state variable... How can I do such a thing in the operator<  method? I tried putting a cout statement in the operator< method and that doesn't seem to work either... thanks!

Comment: @shashydhar: Don't do that. That sort of approach is going to result in undefined behaviour, because it's contrary to how the container works. You define the ordering; once it's a valid ordering, the container takes care of checking for dups. If it can't do that, then your ordering is not valid.

Comment: ok, thanks. I'll try to look at the ordering thing once again.

Answer (score 1):

STL does not use `==` operator for comparison, it uses `<` operator by default and it suffices, because `a != b <=> a<b or b<a`.
You defined a set of pointers to `Node`. So your set does not behave the way you want. You should define `set<Node>`. and also its important to note that STL uses `<` for both insertion and find (i.e. `count` function uses `<`), so you can not use comparison based on `cost` for insertion and comparison based on `state` for finding (your code is like this!).

Answer (score 0):

Thi is the typical example how you would you use `std::set` to find the element exists or not

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

int main(){
    std::set<int> mySet;
    mySet.insert(1);
    mySet.insert(2);
    mySet.insert(3);
    mySet.insert(4);
    mySet.insert(5);

    std::set<int>::iterator pos;
    pos = mySet.find(5);

    if ( pos == mySet.end()){
        std::cout << "Not Found" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Complete example is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

class Node {
public:
    Node(int _state =0, int _cost =0) : state(_state),cost(_cost) {}

    bool operator < (const Node& rhs) const {
        return cost < rhs.cost;
    }
private:
    int state;
    int cost;
};

int main(){
    std::set<Node> myset;
    myset.insert(Node(1,5));
    myset.insert(Node(2,6));
    myset.insert(Node(3,9));

    std::set<Node>::iterator pos, pos1;
    pos = myset.find(Node(1,5));
    pos1 = myset.find(Node(1,7));

    if ( pos == myset.end()){
        std::cout << "Not Found" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "Found" << std::endl;
    }
    if ( pos1 == myset.end()){
        std::cout << "Not Found" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "Found" << std::endl;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you see for example [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) reference page, you see that there is a template parameter `Compare`. You have to implement your own comparison function.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because you declared a ser of **pointers** so that is what the container will compare.

Your comparison method `<` is not going to be used because `std::set` will use standard comparison between pointers. You will also find duplicates in your set if two `Node`s have the same contente but a different address.

Answer (score -2):

> ```
> set<Node*> myset;
> ```

This is set of pointers; it calls `operator==` for pointers, not for `Node`.

You should use `std::set<Node>` if you want to see call of `Node::operator==`.

Comment: No, it doesn't use `operator==`.

Comment: Any way it not calls Node::operator< for std::set<pointer to Node>